# Can't close ul item after it has been opened

Tags: javascript, jquery

The bellow code does work, however once an item has been opened, it can only be closed by opening another item. I want this to happen, but I'd also prefer it if I could close a contact by clicking on itself aswell.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".contacts ul li").on("click", function() {
    $('.contacts ul li').removeClass('selected').children("ul").hide();
    $(this, ".contacts ul li").addClass("selected").children("ul").show();
  });
});


<ul>
        <li>
          <div class="status"></div> Christian
          <ul>
            <li><strong>Phone</strong>: 555.555.555</li>
            <li><strong>Email</strong>: <span class="mail">christian@yahoo.com</span></li>
            <li><strong>Address</strong>: 6539 Wilton Ave, Culver City CA 90234</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="status"></div> Rich
          <ul>
            <li><strong>Phone</strong>: 555.555.555</li>
            <li><strong>Email</strong>: <span class="mail">rich@tripod.com</span></li>
            <li><strong>Address</strong>: 6539 Wilton Ave, Culver City CA 90234</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Provide working code snippet.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: trincot answer is correct. Please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to use `>` in your selectors when you target immediate children only. Since you have nested `li` elements, this does make a difference: without `>`, your click handler will run twice when you click an inner `li` element.

Secondly, you should initialise the DOM so that there is consistency between the presence of the `selected` class and the visibility of the nested `ul` elements.

Finally, you can check whether the clicked `li` is already selected, and depending on that you can hide all nested `ul` elements, or hide all except the `ul` children of the clicked element.

You could do it like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.contacts>ul>li>ul').hide(); // Initialise

  $(".contacts>ul>li").on("click", function() {
    var alreadyOpen = $(this).is(".selected"); // get current status
    $('.contacts>ul>li').removeClass('selected').children("ul").hide();
    if (!alreadyOpen) { // depending on what status was, show 
      $(this).addClass("selected").children("ul").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contacts">
    <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="status"></div> Christian
          <ul>
            <li><strong>Phone</strong>: 555.555.555</li>
            <li><strong>Email</strong>: <span class="mail">christian@yahoo.com</span></li>
            <li><strong>Address</strong>: 6539 Wilton Ave, Culver City CA 90234</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="status"></div> Rich
          <ul>
            <li id="phone2"><strong>Phone</strong>: 555.555.555</li>
            <li id="email2"><strong>Email</strong>: <span class="mail">rich@tripod.com</span></li>
            <li id="address2"><strong>Address</strong>: 6539 Wilton Ave, Culver City CA 90234</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on the etiquette of SO regarding this kind of questions (where you don't mention what you have tried, nor what the problem you encounter in searching for an answer yourself is), however here goes my answer.

Basically you just use the class that you have added when opening an item.

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".contacts ul li").on("click", function() {
    $('.contacts ul li').removeClass('selected').children("ul").hide();
    $(this, ".contacts ul li").addClass("selected").children("ul").show();
  });
  // use the class itself to determine if the item is opened
  $(".contacts ul li.selected").on("click", function() {
    $(this, ".contacts ul li").removeClass('selected').children("ul").hide();
  });
});
```

On a second thought i'm not really sure your code even works. I have written the code above based on your code in an attempt to change as little as possible to your current code.